# How to convert date and time into a numeric value in R

Tags: r, datetime

I am relatively new to R and I have a dataset in which I am trying to convert a date and time into a numeric value. The date and time are in the format 01JUN17:00:00:00 under a variable called pickup_datetime. I have tried using the code

```
cab_small_sample$pickup_datetime <- as.numeric(as.Date(cab_small_sample$pickup_datetime, format = '%d%b%y'))
```

but this way doesn't incorporate time, I tried to add the time format to the format section of code but still did not work. Is there an R function that will convert the data into a numeric value>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R has two main time classes: "Date" and "POSIXct". POSIXct is a datetime class and you can get all the gory details at: `? DateTimeClasses`. The help page for  the formats used at the time of data input, however, are at `?striptime`.

```
cab_small_sample <- data.frame(pickup_datetime = "01JUN17:00:00:00")
cab_small_sample$pickup_dt <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(cab_small_sample$pickup_datetime,
                                                        format = '%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S'))
 cab_small_sample
#   pickup_datetime pickup_dt
#1 01JUN17:00:00:00   1496300400  # seconds since 1970-01-01
```

I find that a "destructive reassignment of values" is generally a bad idea so as a "my (best?) practice rule" I don't assign to the same column until I'm sure I have the code working properly. (And I always leave an untouched copy somewhere safe.)

Comment: Is there a way to make the number a decimal where the time of day is a decimal and the day itself is the whole number? I'm trying to analyze the effect the time of day has and when all expressed as an integer the relationship cannot be seen.

Comment: Fractional days can be converted to seconds by multiplying by 24*60*60. The inverse operation is obviously via division. Excel uses fractional days from 1899-12-31.

Comment: thanks, I was thinking about the functions to do it and totally forgot to consider basic math

Answer (score 1):

`lubridate` is an extremely handy package for dealing with dates. It includes a variety of functions which do the date/time parsing for you, as long as you can provide the order of components. In this case, since your data is in day-month-year-hms form, you can use the `dmy_hms` function.

```
library(lubridate)
cab_small_sample <- dplyr::tibble(
    pickup_datetime = c("01JUN17:00:00:00", "01JUN17:11:00:00"))
cab_small_sample$pickup_POSIX <- dmy_hms(cab_small_sample$pickup_datetime)
```